# How to install pip3 and paramiko in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, paramiko

I am trying to install python `paramiko` using below command:

```
pip3 install paramiko
```

then I got an error:

```
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

then tried to install `pip` using above command, the result is:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>     python3-babel python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-funcsigs python3-gevent python3-greenlet python3-html2text python3-mock python3-ofxparse python3-passlib python3-pbr python3-psutil
>     python3-psycopg2 python3-pydot python3-pyinotify python3-pypdf2 python3-serial python3-stdnum python3-tz python3-usb python3-vatnumber python3-werkzeug python3-yaml
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.

Then I tried to install `paramiko` again but getting the same error, `pip` is not installed.

When I type `pip3 --version` the output is:

```
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip


pip --version
```

Output is:

```
 pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @user1779646, output is Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip3

Comment: try sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: @user1779646, i already treid that command. i posted the output in my question

Comment: error message is saying u have installed pip3

Comment: sudo apt install python3-pip and sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Comment: do u have python3  installed? and try pip3 --version

Comment: python3 --version
Python 3.5.2

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.12

Comment: pip3 --version ?

Comment: out put of `pip3 --version`, i mentined in my question.

Comment: that was pip --version, i'm asking pip3 --version

Comment: This is the out put: The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip`?

Answer (score 1):

For pip on python 3 you have to enter the following command:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I usually do:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install paramiko
```

or

```
python3 -m pip --version
```

instead of

```
pip3 install
```

I don't know why but python -m pip etc ... works better than just pip etc... in my case.

if you really don't have pip (but I thought it comes automatically with python now) you can also get it using:

> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
>   (from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/))

it works on my computer, I don't know why sudo apt-get would not work but you can try this solution instead.